# Different device list data from Playstore console vs Amplitude data

Tags: android, analytics, google-play-console, amplitude, amplitude-analytics

Actually I have a mobile app on the Playstore and I  was figuring out the top 20 devices used by our customers to target them while doing our testing activities.

So I have 2 places to look at:

1. Google play console: (Release --> Reach and devices --> Device cataloge)

> This shows me a list of all installed devices with their numbers. ex: Samsung s22 1000 user , Samsung s23 950 user and so on

2. Amplitude:

> It shows me different list where I can see a device that is not listed in the devices used in google play console. it shows me a device that is ranked 3,4 where in google play console it ranked as 26,29 as most used device.

So my questions are:

1. Does google play console shows these statistics across a time span ?
2. Why there is difference between both amplitude and google play console ?
3. Which can I rely on and take his list into considerations?

Thanks